# how to make same table the tables below

Tags: sql

I have created to tables using code below.
How to have in one table the variables total_kids and tot_0_5 using sql?

```
proc sql;    
    create table total as select *,
    count (distinct var_name1) as total_name
    from data
    group by var_name2
    order by total_name;

proc sql;
    create table total as select (*),
    count (distinct id) as var_name
    from data where age='age_category'
    group by var_name
    order var_name;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select drug,
       count(distinct mbr_id) as total_kids,
       count(distinct case when agecat = '0-5' then mbr_id end) as tot_0_5
from dt
group by drug
order by total_kids;
```

Comment: Hello Gordon,I spent hours to do this you did for a second,i can not find words how to thank you.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Freniks: "i can not find words how to thank you" -- actions speak louder than words ;). The appropriate action to "say" thank you for an answer here is to upvote and accept the answer. Click the up pointing arrow and the check mark left of the answer to do so.